# Mongoose - find by value of key of object in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am trying to grab results if value equals to value of key of an object inside an array.

My **trips** collection looks as below.
Each document in the collection represents a trip (a trip is when a train leaves, until it reaches its final destination). So each trip has an ID and a `stop_times` value, which is an array of stop objects. Each stop has an arrival time, departure time, station ID for the stops and the index (so first stop will be indexed 1, and the last is varying) (note that I also added another "id" key to the document because I don't want to use MongoDB's default object IDs).

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57173a6bf248bbe24ab6e059"), 
    "id" : "20025365_190416", 
    "stop_times" : [
        {
            "arrival" : "05:44:00", 
            "departure" : "05:46:00", 
            "stationId" : NumberInt(37358), 
            "index" : NumberInt(1)
        }, 
        {
            "arrival" : "05:48:00", 
            "departure" : "05:50:00", 
            "stationId" : NumberInt(37365), 
            "index" : NumberInt(2)
        }'
        ...
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57223a6bf448bbe25ab1e053"), 
    "id" : "13241404_190416", 
    "stop_times" : [
        {
            "arrival" : "22:02:00", 
            "departure" : "22:04:00", 
            "stationId" : NumberInt(37342), 
            "index" : NumberInt(1)
        }, 
        {
            "arrival" : "22:07:00", 
            "departure" : "22:09:00", 
            "stationId" : NumberInt(37361), 
            "index" : NumberInt(2)
        }'
        ...
    ]
}
...
...
...
```

What I am trying to do, is grab a **trip** by the following credentials:
Grab a trip, where the stop ID equals for example 37358. So the search is very deep here and I am confused about how to do it. I tried the following:

```
global.models.Trip.find({ stop_times: { $elemMatch: { stationId: 37358 }}})
```

But I get an empty array as a result.

This is the Schema:

```
var stopTimes = {
  arrival: String,
  departure: String,
  stationId: Number,
  index: Number
};

var schema = {
  id: {
    type: Number,
    index: true
  },
  stop_times: [stopTimes]
};
```

Any help or reference would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `global.models.Trip.find({"stop_times.stationId": 37358})` should do the trick actualy you do not need `$elemMatch` for your query